# How do I use the CloudBees SDK (command line interface) on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I am running a job in DEV@cloud on cloudbees - but I want to use the CloudBees SDK/CLI, how do I do this from within the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scripting [Bees SDK in Jenkins doc](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Scripting+Bees+SDK+in+Jenkins) includes a good write-up about this.

Firstly, you use a freestyle job, then install the Bees SDK as part of it:

```
# INSTALL AND CONFIGURE BEES SDK
export BEES_HOME=/opt/cloudbees/cloudbees-sdk/
export PATH=$PATH:$BEES_HOME
if [ ! -d ~/.bees ]; then
    bees init -f -a <your account name here> -ep us -k $BEES_API -s $BEES_SECRET
fi
```

Then set the secrets in your Jenkins setup for BEES_API BEES_SECRET - and then you can use bees SDK commands.

You can install any plugins you need from here as well.